# ipython code snippets in ReST create unwanted files

Tags: ipython, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Consider this ReST text from the [Xarray documentation](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/master/doc/dask.rst#chunking-and-performance):

> Once you've manipulated a Dask array, you can still write a dataset
>   too big to fit into memory back to disk by using
>   `:py:meth:~xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf` in the usual way.
>
> ```
> .. ipython:: python
>
>     ds.to_netcdf('manipulated-example-data.nc')
> ```
>
> By setting the compute argument to False,
>   `:py:meth:~xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf` will return a Dask delayed object
>   that can be computed later.

When we build the documentation, this snippet actually *creates the file* `manipulated-example-data.nc`. We obviously don't want this file in the repository. I don't know much about the `ipython` directive in ReST but there must be a standard way to handle this, rather than just adding this stuff to the `.gitignore`. Anyone know?